# Create Viewmodel from Controller / Model. Populate lists from database

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, entity-framework-6, viewmodel

I'm working on my first WPF MVVM application. I created a database and wrote queries to fetch album names and song names. Now I want to fill a list in my View with the album names and a second list with corresponding songs. I'm new to c# and WPF. I'd like to know how a view model would like for my controller would look like.

My controller:

```cs
    public class BandManagerController
    {
        private bandkramEntities _context;

        public BandManagerController()
        {
            _context = new bandkramEntities();
        }

        public List<AlbumData> GetAlbumList()     
        {
            return _context.albums
                .Select(a => new AlbumData
                {
                    AlbumID = a.AlbumID,
                    AlbumName = a.AlbumName,
                })
                .ToList();
        }

        public List<SongData> GetSongList(int albumID)
        {
            return _context.songs
                .Where(s => s.AlbumID == albumID)
                .Select(s => new SongData
                {
                    SongID = s.SongID,
                    SongName = s.SongName
                })
                .ToList();
        }
    }
```

I created a helper class with the NotifyOfPropertyChange class and a song and album data class:

AlbumData.cs

```cs
    public class AlbumData
    {
        public string AlbumName { get; set; }

        public int AlbumID { get; set; }
    }
```

SongData.cs

```cs
    public class SongData
    { 
            public string SongName { get; set; }

            public int SongID { get; set; }            
    }
```

For a better overview I want to split my Viewmodel into 4 main parts.

1. SongViewModel.cs

```cs
    public class SongViewModel : NotifyOfPropertyChange
    {
        public SongViewModel()
        {

        }

        public string SongName { get; set; }

        public int SongID { get; set; }
    }
```

2. AlbumViewModel.cs

```cs
    public class AlbumViewModel : NotifyOfPropertyChange
    {
        public AlbumViewModel()
        {

        }

        public string AlbumName { get; set; }

        public int AlbumID { get; set; }
    }
```

3. SongListViewModel.cs
4. AlbumListViewModel.cs

I would like to know how 3. and 4. would have to look like to fill the album list with the album names and show corresponding songs in a second list.

Comment: Not really sure why are you calling your service a controller, controller is usually found in MVC not MVVM. Structure wise, I would have a Main View Model which would hold the list of songs and albums, then in your view I would have 2 lists (ListView or ListBox) then bind the lists to those controls and the selected value of albums would in the viewmodel change the collection of songs, raise INPC, job done.

Answer (score 0):

With MVVM you would lose the controller and just have a ViewModel. There you would have your lists as such(including a notify property changed)

```
  private ObservableCollection<SongData> _songList;
  public ObservableCollection<SongData> SongList
  {
    get { return _songList; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _songList, value, () => SongList); }
  }
```

Then you would load this list at some point

```
public void LoadSongData(int albumID)
    {
     Using(YourContext _context = new YourContext)
     {
        SongList = new ObservableCollection(_context.songs
            .Where(s => s.AlbumID == albumID)
            .Select(s => new SongData
            {
                SongID = s.SongID,
                SongName = s.SongName
            })
            .ToList());
      }
    }
```